# EXT GWT Bind Selected Items to a new empty grid

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, datasource, gxt

I am using one grid to select items, and another to display the selected items. I am having trouble updating the new grid.

In pseudo code:

```
selectionGrid = new Grid();

selectionGrid.addlistener(new listener {
    update();
});

void update() {

targetGrid = new Grid(selectionGrid.getstore().getselecteditems(), columns);
}
```

I'm able to update the targetgrid the first time, but have trouble updating it again after a new selection.

Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much it - make the two grids, one with the original items, the other with an empty `ListStore`. The update call should `store.addAll(selected)`, though probably `store.clear()` first.

These methods assume GXT 3 - in GXT 2, I think it is `store.add(selected)` and `store.removeAll()`. In 2 you may also find that the `Events.SelectionChange` isn't fired by Grid, but by it's `SelectionModel` - read the javadoc to be sure what events each class fires. In GXT 3, the events are made clear by the exposed `HasSelectionHandlers` interfaces, indicating that you can add a handler for selection events.

If this still doesn't work, consider posting an almost working example to demonstrate exactly what you've tried.